# Can I do client- server communication between Android mobile and local xampp server

Tags: android, server, client, communication

I want to learn  client - server communication in Android. As per my understating, to communicate with the server we need a valid URL. My doubt is that, can I communicate Android mobile client with the local xammp server???? If yes, please explain me... 
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do that if you are using android emulator then use http://10.0.2.2 ip address to access localhost, for genymotion use this http://10.0.3.2.
You can also use Google Chrome's port forwarding but you need google chrome on computer and emulator or device.
if you want to access localhost using port forwarding then open following address on google chrome `chrome://inspect` and enable port forwarding and set port and ip address.